# How to receive all the meta information of a post ?

Tags: post-meta

How can I get all the meta information of a particular post_id, if my meta_key = 'title' and meta_value = 'My Content Template'
meta_key = 'download_url' and meta_value = 'http://www.example.com/pdf/pdfinfo.pdf/'

and i have 10 meta key and meta value for the same post.
How can i get all the meta information in a tabular format such as:

```
Title           URL  
My Content     http://www.example.com/pdf/pdfinfo.pdf/
Download Data   http://www.example.com/pdf/phparray.pdf/
```

I have tried below code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Download URL</th>
</tr>
<?php 
  $stored_titles = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title' );
   $stored_urls = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'download_url');
?>
<tr>
<?php  foreach($stored_titles as $title) { ?>
<td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
<?php  } ?>
<?php  foreach($stored_urls as $url) { ?>
<td><?php echo $url; ?></td>
<?php  } ?>

</tr>

</table>
```

Please any one help to get this done.

Comment: OK, wait... What custom fields exactly are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is what you wanted, but let me try...

```
<?php
    $titles = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title' );
    $urls = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title' );
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Download URL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ( $titles as $k => $title ) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo esc_html($title); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo esc_html( array_key_exists( $k, $urls ) ? $urls[$k] : '' ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```